# QGIS 3.12 GPS Panel

Tags: qgis, gps, usb

I am using QGIS 3.12 and I want to see my real time location on my canvas. I have a GPS receiver plugged into my USB port. It looks like it is connected but I can't see my position (image attached). What can I do or is there another way to see my real tome position on my QGIS project?

[image: S]

Comment: Did you click on the wrench (configure) button and fill that in?

Comment: I marked Autodetect. Do I have to choose a diffrent option?

Comment: In looking at your question again, the text suggests the issue is seeing your position as against just getting a connection.  If so I do have one suggestion which is to increase the cursor size.  Move the slider up and down until you get what you want, which might vary with the scale, I can't recall.

Comment: Ok but also whan I switch to the identity tag all the numbers are 0.00 (lat lon etc). Thats the reason I thimk I have a problem with my connection

Comment: You should see lat long numbers and time.  The device I have here is a Windows tablet computer with a built in GPS chip.  The project itself is in UTM Nad 83 Z19.  I guess I've run out of suggestions.  If you don't get any other suggestions you might try the QGIS user mailing list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it Jhons